# How to tag a passing build?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I saw a configuration option that allows tagging every build, but it seems this would just needlessly pollute the tag history. Is there a way in Jenkins to tag a build only once it has been marked as passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, using the [Flexible Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin).

This plugin will allow you to wrap post-build actions in a `Run condition`.

All this really boils down to is, installing & using that plugin, you can wrap your git publish in a `Run condition` using the `Current build status` as it's condition, setting it to only run when the entire build has passed (success).